# Setting the index.html path when using cordova-plugin-ionic-webview in cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm not using Ionic, just plain Cordova. I am forced to use **cordova-plugin-ionic-webview** plugin to avoid the UIWebView warning from Apple.

The problem is that my index.html is inside another folder (www/cordova_onsen). In plain cordova I can point it using the . This does not seem to work with *cordova-plugin-ionic-webview* plugin installed.

Due to some constraints I cannot move the files outside of the cordova_onsen folder. I've tried using the *cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine* plugin also but it introduced more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to open a worksplace instead xcodeproject when you work in xCode, in my case my build failed, because external plugin was missing, after opening worksplace(not a xcodeproject) my build was success.